# Issues installing pytorch for OS X with conda

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I used to have pytorch working for python 3 on OS X but now I can't get it to install automatically for some reason (I don't want to do from source).

I did:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

as the website suggested... then I got a `mkl` error so I installed it but it still complains about it:

```
(FTIR_py3) brandomiranda~/home_simulation_research/FTIR/FTIR_proj $ conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications:


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Dependencies missing in current osx-64 channels:
  - pytorch -> mkl >=2018
  - torchvision -> pytorch >=0.3 -> mkl >=2018

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda mkl

You may need to install the anaconda-client command line client with

    conda install anaconda-client
```

but I do have mkl:

```
(FTIR_py3) brandomiranda~/home_simulation_research/FTIR/FTIR_proj $ conda install mkl
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/brandomiranda/miniconda3/envs/FTIR_py3:
#
mkl                       2017.0.3                      0
```

anyone know whats going on? it used to work a few days ago...

---

longer thread on pytorch forum:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/issues-installing-pytorch-for-os-x-with-conda/11496

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in PyTorch forum, I think you should first install `MKL`. Your error trace also says that `MKL` is missing in your system. You can install `MKL` by doing:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda mkl
```

After this, install `pytorch` and `torchvision` by

```
$ conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision
```

Comment: @CharlieParker good! It works because we put `-c pytorch` immediately after `conda install`. By this, first we're selecting the `channel` *pytorch* and then we're install the package *pytorch* and *torchvision*. This way of installation is clear to understand and will always work :) The way this installation command written in pytorch page will produce unexpected behaviour. So, I'd suggest you to follow this convention while installing any package in conda environment or in a `virtualenv`. Merry Christmas!

Comment: By why did u have to say pytorch twice? And how did u know this was right? I think Im still confused about that...merry christmas! :)

Answer (score 2):

Update conda first with `conda update conda` and try again.

It helped in my case.

Disclaimer: I didn't come up with this myself, but rather copied from [github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4090).